# Ember.js and Canvas

Tags: ember.js

Hi how I get the canvas '2d' context in an Ember View? The following Code doesn't work.
 I get the canvas element of dom, but not the context of '2d'.

```
App.Canvas = Ember.View.extend({
 tagName: 'canvas',
 quader: function () {
        return this.get('controller.model');
 }.property('controller.model'),
 didInsertElement: function(){

     var canvas = this.$('#id'); // get the Element
     var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); // --> get Error

    // Filled triangle
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(25,25);
    ctx.lineTo(105,25);
    ctx.lineTo(25,105);
    ctx.fill();

    // Stroked triangle
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(125,125);
    ctx.lineTo(125,45);
    ctx.lineTo(45,125);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke(); 
 }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following your example, a way to access the element defined by the `tagName` from inside a ember view would be done like so:

```
var canvas = this.get('element');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

`this.get('element')` get's the DOM element defined in the `tagName` property of the view, in your case the `canvas` element

Here a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uruhoq/1/edit).

Hope it helps